# PowerBI exporting dataset to document with template

Tags: powerbi

I'm interested in Microsoft PowerBI and I want to export a dataset to PDF, doc(x) or HTML using a template. I don't want to create graphs or dashboards, I just want to display the data in a visually appealing way. I would like to be able to edit the template and possibly style it using css or some kind of template editor.

Is this possible using PowerBI?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Excel instead of Power BI. You can copy the Power Query code verbatim, so you will get the same data that the Power BI data model has.

In Excel, you can create pivot tables from the output or just style the output from the query as desired.

Then you can refresh the query and save the result as a PDF. This can be automated with VBA.

Comment: So you're saying I can do all this with just Excel? I would like to retrieve the data from a NoSQL database, is this also possible with Excel/VBA? Or do I need to write some sort of connector beforehand?

Comment: Power Query is a free add-in for Microsoft for Excel 2010 and 2013 and it is built into Excel 2016 in the Data ribbon. There are some differences in the connectors, but I don't see NoSQL in either Power BI OR in Power Query, so I don't know how you get that data right now. But, yes, using Power Query and VBA in Excel is absolutely doable.